# Node.js change value from required object

Tags: javascript, node.js

--- main.js ---

```
var myModule = require('./module_a.js');
var value = 0;

myModule.set(35);
console.log("myModule.data:", myModule.data);
console.log("myModule.get():",myModule.get());
console.log(myModule);
```

--- module_a.js ---

```
exports.data = 10; 
exports.set = function(value) {
    data = value;
};
exports.get = function() {
    return data;
};
```

I have expected that the `main.js`'s result is 35 each in 2 `console.log()`. But, the result is 10 each.

I don't know why this happens. From `require` method, variable `myModule` is a object which has `data`, function `set`, function `get`.

So, `myModule.set(35)` should have to change `myModule` object's data to 35. But, it is still 10.

If I use `this.data = value` and `return this.data`. It works as I expected. But not in the first case(my above source code)

Why this happen??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a local `data` variable in your `module`.

Try changing this line

```
exports.data = 10;
```

to

```
var data = 10;
exports.data = data;
```

Comment: But, myModule is a object which also has an `data` value. So, it should have to change its `data` value.

Comment: @allen - no, you have `exports.data`, but you don't have `data` which is what you're trying to change in the methods. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @adeneno - Then, what's the `data` shown in object `myModule`?? And, what `data` do `set` and `get` refer to??

Answer (score 1):

Module

```
exports.myObj = {
    data: 10,
    set: function (value) {
        this.data = value;
    },
    get: function () {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Main

```
var myModule = require('./module_a.js').myObj;
var value = 0;

myModule.set(35);
console.log("myModule.data:", myModule.data);
console.log("myModule.get():",myModule.get());
console.log(myModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this assignment `data = value;` the javascript engine will check if you've defined the var in the file and if you didn't define it, it will define the var in the module namespace if you are in node.js and in the global namespace if you are on the browser, and this is a very bad practice in any case.

The assignment that you are doing here `exports.data = data;` it creates an extra field in the exports object. You can understand that the `data` variable that got defined in the global namespace has nothing to do with the field that got defined in the exports object.

Comment: @Maxx, yes this is correct for node. I' ll update the answer.